# Why is an element in the countable product of real numbers regarded as a sequence?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, product-space

A sequence of real numbers is a just an enumerated list of real numbers. Now in my lecture notes it is mentioned that an element of the countable product topological space $\mathbb{R}^w$ (Tychonoff topology) can be regarded as a sequence of real numbers. I'm a bit confused by this statement. How can an element of the product topology be a real sequence? Could someone clarify this with a concrete example?

Comment: You probably meant an element, not a subset. This is pretty simple. An element of $\mathbf R^\omega$ *is* a function from $\omega$ to $\mathbf R$, i.e. a sequence.

Comment: @tomasz yes, you're right I meant an element.

Comment: An element is a countable-length tuple of real numbers. Is that a sequence?

Comment: @mathripper By definition, sequences of objects (sets, for ultimately they are the objects of set theory) are families of objects indexed by either $\mathbb{N}$ or by a final segment of $\mathbb{N}$, of the form $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n\geqslant k\}$. In your case, $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ consists precisely of the set of all families of objects indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ whose every component belongs to $\mathbb{R}$. This is precisely the set of all sequences of real numbers. More generally, $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of all sequences of elements of $A$.

Comment: An element of $\mathbb R^3$ is a real sequence, one with 3 entries $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Similarly for $\mathbb R^4$, $\mathbb R^5$, and so on. So $\mathbb R^\omega$ is just a generalization with infinitely many coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably think of $\Bbb R^\omega$ as the set of "$\omega$-tuples" (by analogy with $n$-tuples) with coordinates elements of $\Bbb R$.  But then one has the sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_n:=\text{the n-th  coordinate of x}$ for any element $x\in\Bbb R^\omega$.

But what's also kind of nice is the functional analysis flavor of considering $\Bbb R^\omega$ as the set of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$.  Then we simply have, for each $f\in\Bbb R^\omega$, the sequence $x_n:=f(n)$.