# Having Trouble Understanding How One Set Maps On To Another

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

This is almost verbatim from my textbook :

"Our  previous  examples  of  vector spaces, $R^n$ and  $R^\infty$, are special cases of the vector space $R^S$ *(where S is any non-empty set)* because a list of length $n$ of numbers in $R$ can be thought of as a function from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $R$, and a sequence of numbers in $R$ can be thought of as a function from the set of positive integers to $R$."

Something I do understand :

Ok, let's take the vector space $R^{[0,1]}$ which would be the set of all Real-Valued functions $f$ such that $f : [0,1] \rightarrow R$.  So, for example, $f(x)=5x \in R^{[0,1]}$.  That I get.

But, how can "a list of length $n$ of numbers in $R$ can be thought of as a function from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $R$"?

Right, so, if we're in $R^2$ then we've got $f:\{1,2\} \rightarrow R$.  But how is some ordered pair in $R^2$, say (7, -3) related to the set $\{1,2\}$ and *what exactly* is the thing in $R$ that is being mapped to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordered pair $x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ can be identified with the function $x : \{1,2\} \to \mathbb R$ such that $x(1) = x_1$ and $x(2) = x_2$. Also, when you write "$f(x)=5x \in \mathbb R^{[0,1]}$" this is wrong. If $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is given by the *rule* $f(x)=5x$, then $f$ *is* an element of $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Thank you!  I also appreciate the correction.  Could you elaborate just a little on it?  What exactly is meant by "If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ is given by the rule $f(x)=5x$"?

Comment: Sure! Whenever you want to define a function you need three things: a set that works as the domain of the function, another set that works as the codomain of the function, and the correspondence rule (a precise definition of where you want to send each element of the domain, for example, a formula of the type $f(x) =  \cdots$ for each $x$ in the domain of $f$). So, when you write the symbol $f(x)$, this is just the value of $f$ at $x$, $f$ is the function, not $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

A list of $n$ real numbers is something like $$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$$

We can view this as a function $f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(1)=x_1\\f(2)=x_2\\\vdots\\f(n)=x_n$$

Comment: Thanks!  I initially thought it was this but the more I thought the more confused I got.  I really wish the textbooks would be more explicit sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The functional analysis notation $Y^X$ means the space of all functions $f:X\to Y$.  This is a vector space in a natural way when $Y$ is a vector space.

So here we are just employing that notation.  That is, each element of $\Bbb R^n$, say, is an $n$-tuple $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.  And that in turn corresponds to a unique function $f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\Bbb R$, given simply by $f(i)=x_i$.

The extension to infinite sequences is straight forward.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3906627/403337).